# Why can't access to glassfish admin console remotely?

Tags: ssl, https, glassfish, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a virtual machine with Centos7 in virtual box. I have installed there glassfish 5.0 from here: [Full platform - glassfish 5.0](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download). I simply unzipped the folder in /opt. I'm using "host-only".

The following is my java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

I have enabled secure admin with the following command:

```
asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 enable-secure-admin
```

I go in vm shell and digit "ifconfig" to know the ip.
Then, I go in power shell (win + x) of my windows host and type, to connect via ssh:

```
ssh user@x.x.x.x
```

Then:

```
cd /opt/glassfish5/bin
./asadmin start-domain domain1
```

Then I come back to my host, I open google chrome and:

1. http://x.x.x.x:8080 seems fine
2. http://x.x.x.x:4848 forces to https and then the browser tells me it's impossible to reach the website

I have tried to uninstall secure-admin (at least before glassfish gave me the exception which said that secure-admin was needed for DAS or anything like that):

```
./asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 disable-secure-admin
```

but I get the following exception:

```
NCLS-ADMIN-00010
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
Command disable-secure-admin failed.
```

I get the following exception in my log after calling admin console:

```
[2018-05-16T16:35:59.644+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain] [tid: _ThreadID=42 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1526481359644] [levelValue: 900] [[
  GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/SupportedEllipticCurvesExtension
        at sun.security.ssl.HelloExtensions.<init>(HelloExtensions.java:82)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ClientHello.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:362)
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:223)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:984)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:924)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:921)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1379)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLUtils.executeDelegatedTask(SSLUtils.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:708)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:622)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:334)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is your version of Java is **too new for GlassFish**. I already answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49998266/212224

To stop the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` you need to use a version of Java no higher than **`8u151`**

> This is due to a change in internal JDK classes which Grizzly uses for
> HTTP/2.
>
> GlassFish 5.0 does **not** have the latest version of Grizzly which is
> compatible with the latest Java 8 updates. If you are using GlassFish
> 5.0 and see these errors, you have 2 choices:
>
> 1. Downgrade Java to **8u152** or earlier
> 2. [Download the latest GlassFish 5.0.1 nightly](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0.1/nightly/latest-glassfish.zip), where this should be fixed
>
> Ref:
> https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22436#issuecomment-374829430

Comment: I tried and actually it worked downgrading jdk to 1.8.0 u152

Comment: I'll wait just a while to see eventually other replies, then I'll vote.

Comment: @Mike im running ubuntu 16.0.4 and glassfish5.0.1 and java 1.8 131. but having the same issue .after enable-secure-admin, i cant access to port 4848 admin page