# Glassfish 5 Server's HTTPS Not Working "Out of the Box"

Tags: ssl, glassfish, tls1.2

I am reading this tutorial page: https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/security-intro006.html Which explains that I should be able to view the SSL version of the home page (index.html) by going to the following URL: https://localhost:8181. However, when I point my browser at this address I receive an error that is shown in Figure 1.

I have a feeling configuring this could take hours the first time. Does anyone have a tutorial that can help me configure HTTPS on my loopback address in Glassfish?

I found links to documentation on the administration console, running on port 4848, but this is tough to understand. The quick start guide does not cover this aspect. I mean there is a quick start guide also on the administration console but configuring HTTPS is not covered.

[image]
*Figure 1*: HTTPS/SSL page not working - glassfish v5

**FIXED**
I think Mike helped me fix this problem. Thank-you Mike! That was a solution I would not of come up with on my own. Thank-you for getting me out of that hole.

However, when I now access this secure web address on my loopback address, https://localhost:8181, I actually see the webpage and not the error page shown in Figure 1. However, there is a red line through the protocol in the URL and the words explaining that the connection is not secure. **How can I make the connection secure?**

[image]
*Figure 2*: Glassfish HTTPS home page working but not secure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the logs, you will likely see something like this after you try to visit the secure page:

```
[2018-05-21T14:34:31.982+0100] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain] [tid: _ThreadID=100 _ThreadName=http-listener-2(2)] [timeMillis: 1526909671982] [levelValue: 900] [[
  GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/SupportedEllipticCurvesExtension
        at sun.security.ssl.HelloExtensions.<init>(HelloExtensions.java:82)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ClientHello.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:362)
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:223)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:984)
```

The solution to this is to **downgrade your version of Java to a version below 8u161**.

[I answered this in more detail in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50374495/212224) but, if you do not like the idea of downgrading Java, you could either use [the latest GlassFish 5.0.1 nightly](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0.1/nightly/latest-glassfish.zip) or [switch to Payara 5, which is derived from GlassFish](https://www.payara.fish/downloads) and should work the same in most cases.

***Edit:*** Note that, after making one of these changes, you will still need to add a security exception so that your browser accepts the self-signed certificate, but the page should work with no further issues; I verified this myself with Java 8u144

Comment: Mike, thank-you for the help. This seems to work but there is a red line through the https in the URL. I was not expecting the red line and the words showing that the connection is not secure.  Please see a screenshot of this in my question. I will post the picture there as I cannot here in the comments. I downgraded to Java jdk 1.8.0_152, btw.

Comment: Mike, is there anyway to have the connection be secure? As of now there is the aforementioned red line through the protocol in the address and the words "not secure" with a red triangle with an exclamation point inside of said triangle.

Comment: You need to either get your browser to trust the demo certificate that came with GlassFish (bad idea) or get a valid SSL certificate for your domain (good idea). LetsEncrypt is the best/easiest way (because it's free). Once you've done that, you can follow these instructions: https://blog.payara.fish/securing-payara-server-with-custom-ssl-certificate

Comment: Wow, thank-you again Mike for the very helpful help with this problem.

Comment: This page explains a simpler way to create a certificate for localhost: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Comment: Although adding a certificate to localhost is not so simple. I have no idea and all the tools are for Linux. I may give up trying to create a certificate for the localhost.