# Glassfish connection to MS SQL server database

Tags: java, sql-server, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have evaluation copy of MS SQL server installed with database AdventureWorks2016 attached to it and have run Glassfish on localhost:4848. TCP/IP connection is allowed on SQL server (Configuration Manager) and TCP port is 1433. I have downloaded Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.0 for SQL Server from [Microsoft JDBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and unzipped it in C:\ and set a CLASSPATH variable to point to it and have placed a copy of it in 
C:\Program Files\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib. I use Windows Authentication to connect to MS SQL server.
I create AdventureWorks2016 connection pool with all defaults. When I ping it, I am getting

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.(Lsun/security/ssl/ProtocolVersion;Lsun/security/ssl/CipherSuite;Ljava/util/Collection;Lsun/security/ssl/SessionId;Ljava/lang/String;I)V sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.(Lsun/security/ssl/ProtocolVersion;Lsun/security/ssl/CipherSuite;Ljava/util/Collection;Lsun/security/ssl/SessionId;Ljava/lang/String;I)

What am I missing?
java jdk is java 8 (jdk1.8.0_191) and Glassfish 5.0.

I have downgraded to java8u151. Now the  error, when I am pinging is :

> Ping Connection Pool failed for AdventureWorks2016. Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Unsupported curveId: 29". ClientConnectionId:ebe27ff7-0ce1-4e9d-95fd-52133be8ee01 Please check the server.log for more details.

As I have said, I am using Windows Authentication on the server, because I do not need anything else on my laptop and because this has worked first, when I installed MS SQL Server. Now I try

> jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;

for the URL property, but it did not have an effect.

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` ==> Mismatched compile/runtime versions of library(ies)

Answer (score 3):

The prolem "Unsupported curveId: 29" was solved.

Here is my setting in Glassfish (Java8 build 152):"-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false".

See the image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting a known issue with GlassFish 5.0 and Java versions higher than 8u161.

from [the last time I answered this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50450249/212224):

> The solution to this is to **downgrade your version of Java to a
>   version below 8u161**.
>
> [I answered this in more detail in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50374495/212224) but, if you do
>   not like the idea of downgrading Java, you could either use [the
>   latest GlassFish 5.0.1 nightly](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0.1/nightly/latest-glassfish.zip) or [switch to Payara 5, which is
>   derived from GlassFish](https://www.payara.fish/downloads) and should work the same in most cases.
>
> ***Edit:*** Note that, after making one of these changes, you will still need to add a security exception so that your browser accepts
>   the self-signed certificate, but the page should work with no further
>   issues; I verified this myself with Java 8u144

Comment: I have downgraded. The full description is above, as addition to my initial explanation.

Comment: I have added a security exception to the browser for http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf and stll getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @VinnhCC solve the problem if you put the option in 'server-config' instead 'default-config'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a specific version of JDK for this to work: 181. I could only get this to work consistently with the MS SQL Server JDBC driver if I use JDK version 181. I wish there was a better way of using more up to date version of JDK but unfortunately this is it.