# Secure Admin must be enabled to access the DAS remotely - access Glassfish config page

Tags: ubuntu, server, glassfish, ubuntu-18.04, glassfish-5

My environment is Ubuntu 18.10. It is a new installation, no firewall or processes that run on Glassfish ports.

I installed Glassfish 5 on the server. Java 8, because Glassfish doesn't support any newer. And when I tried to access my config page, of course it gave me a "Secure Admin must be enabled to access the DAS remotely".

Then I proceed to change my admin password with the following commands:

```
./asadmin start-domain

./asadmin change-admin-password
```

- I entered my password and retype it =>

> "Command change-admin-password executed successfully."

```
./asadmin enable-secure-admin
```

=>

> "You must restart all running servers for the change in secure admin to take effect. Command enable-secure-admin executed successfully."

```
./asadmin stop-domain
./asadmin start-domain
```

That is it and it should work. My server is running, I can access my main Glassfish page, but when I'm trying to access the config page it says it didn't find any page with that port.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm struggling with this simple installation.

Comment: Which URL do you use? Anything in the `server.log`?

Comment: server_ip:default_port  and sever_ip:default_admin_cofig_page. I've tried to install another domain on other admin config ip, creating domain, I issued the same comands with the domain and the port mentioned

Comment: and the server.log their is an java exception

[2018-12-06T11:36:51.399+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _Thr$
  GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/SupportedEllipticPointFormatsExtension
        at sun.security.ssl.HelloExtensions.<init>(HelloExtensions.java:84)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ClientHello.<init>
....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the exception you posted in your comment, you are hitting a known issue with GlassFish 5.0 and Java versions higher than 8u161.

from [the last time I answered this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50450249/212224):

> The solution to this is to **downgrade your version of Java to a
>   version below 8u161**.
>
> [I answered this in more detail in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50374495/212224) but, if you do
>   not like the idea of downgrading Java, you could either use [the
>   latest GlassFish 5.0.1 nightly](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0.1/nightly/latest-glassfish.zip) or [switch to Payara 5, which is
>   derived from GlassFish](https://www.payara.fish/downloads) and should work the same in most cases.
>
> ***Edit:*** Note that, after making one of these changes, you will still need to add a security exception so that your browser accepts
>   the self-signed certificate, but the page should work with no further
>   issues; I verified this myself with Java 8u144