# Glassfish server 5 restart-domain displays NCLS-ADMIN-00010 after enable-secure-admin

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, server, glassfish

With Glassfish server 5, restart-domain displays NCLS-ADMIN-00010 after enable-secure-admin.

```
C:\glassfish-5.0.1\glassfish5\glassfish\bin>asadmin start-domain
Waiting for domain1 to start .......................
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: C:\glassfish-5.0.1\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1
Log File: C:\glassfish-5.0.1\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.

C:\glassfish-5.0.1\glassfish5\glassfish\bin>asadmin change-admin-password
Enter admin user name [default: admin]>admin
Enter the admin password>
Enter the new admin password>
Enter the new admin password again>
Command change-admin-password executed successfully.

C:\glassfish-5.0.1\glassfish5\glassfish\bin>asadmin enable-secure-admin
Enter admin user name>  admin
Enter admin password for user "admin">
You must restart all running servers for the change in secure admin to take effect.
Command enable-secure-admin executed successfully.

C:\glassfish-5.0.1\glassfish5\glassfish\bin>asadmin restart-domain
NCLS-ADMIN-00010
NCLS-ADMIN-00010
NCLS-ADMIN-00010
NCLS-ADMIN-00010
NCLS-ADMIN-00010
NCLS-ADMIN-00010
```

I've tried to:

1. Downgrade Java to 8u152 or earlier.
2. Download the latest GlassFish 5.0.1 nightly.

But the above suggestions do not work.

Also, when I use the enable-secure-admin with stop-domain and start-domain, Glassfish does not display on localhost:4848.

Can anyone give me any help?

Comment: I already answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63942176/7152693

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in version 6.1 by:
setting correct javajdk in /glassfishX/glassfish/config/asenv.bat or asenv.conf
(glassfish 5.0, 5.01 and 5.1 needs jdk 251/252 or LOWEST
glassfish 6 needs jdk 9 or 11 - i use 11 and its fine)

stop domain

kill java task

**delete folder:**

linux: in /home/user who run glassfish/.gfclient

windows: c:\users\user who run glassfish.gfclient

start domain

perhaps you will see other error in upload/deploy about **path=null or missing**

stop-domain

this you can fix with editing /glassfish/glassfish/modules/console-common.jar (open it with your zip/rar aplication). Find applications/uploadFrame.jsf,

open it, edit the tag <sun:form id="form"> and change it to <sun:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">.

Save the uploadFrame.jsf, update the jar with the "new" jsf.

start domain

I have wasted a lot of time to fix all things upcomming with the new versions, i think this is all.

Answer (score 0):

**POSSIBLE REASON: ASADMIN CLI IS LACKING PERMISSIONS ON THE FILE SYSTEM**

Check if the directory where the asadmin cli is storing his data has write permissions. We are using Payara in a container platform without write permissions on the file system by default. Thus we had to mount a extra volume in our container to gain write permissions and had to change the working directory of the asadmin cli.

The default working directory where the cli is storing his data is `$HOME/.gfclient`. You can change the location by setting the env variable `AS_GFCLIENT` in different ways:

```
Dockerfile:
ENV AS_GFCLIENT=/tmp/.gfclient

Shell:
export AS_GFCLIENT=/tmp/.gfclient

glassfish/config/asenv.conf (Linux):
AS_GFCLIENT="/tmp/.gfclient"

glassfish/config/asenv.bat (Windows):
set AS_GFCLIENT=/tmp/.gfclient
```

**I would recommend to use the Dockerfile variant if you build your own Payara base image.** Otherwise the Shell variant could be your choice in the entrypoint of your Docker container. Using asenv files is not that pretty in my opinion. Because when changing asenv.conf or asenv.bat keep in mind that these files will be overwritten when installing a new version of payara.

Source code ref: https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/10791ff76bcb6c10199d9c7b8dade88634a19f05/nucleus/common/common-util/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/security/store/AsadminSecurityUtil.java#L91

*Why i had to deal with the NCLS-ADMIN-00010 code:*
When executing `asadmin stop-domain` command after starting the domain with `asadmin start-domain` command, the cli failed to stop the domain. The output of the cli was the following:

```
Command stop-domain failed.
No domains are currently running.
CLI306: Warning - The server located at /data/local/domain/domain1 is not running.
NCLS-ADMIN-00010
```