# Glassfish 5.1 server not starting after enable-secure-admin (NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/HelloExtension)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-8

I have a glassfish server version 5.1 on linux (ubuntu 18.04). I could start it without any issues, but after enabling the secure-admin via

> asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 enable-secure-admin

the server seems to fail to start permanently. I cannot `stop-domain` or `restart-domain`, although `start-domain` says that there is something running on port 4848. So I have to manually kill the process.

server.log:

```
    [2020-08-01T18:02:53.647+0000] [glassfish 5.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=58 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1596304973647] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/HelloExtension
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLExtension.<clinit>(SSLExtension.java:225)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLConfiguration.getEnabledExtensions(SSLConfiguration.java:369)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloKickstartProducer.produce(ClientHello.java:562)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.kickstart(SSLHandshake.java:509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.kickstart(ClientHandshakeContext.java:110)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:234)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:393)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:727)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$200(SSLSocketImpl.java:74)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1012)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:229)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:150)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:175)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.rebind(GenericURLContext.java:251)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:433)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:433)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:642)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter.start(RMIConnectorStarter.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.startConnector(JMXStartupService.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.run(JMXStartupService.java:322)
]]

[2020-08-02T09:21:48.272+0000] [glassfish 5.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1596360108272] [levelValue: 900] [[
  GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.createSSLEngineImpl(SSLContextImpl.java:610)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.engineCreateSSLEngine(SSLContextImpl.java:202)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.createSSLEngine(SSLContext.java:361)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator.createSSLEngine(SSLEngineConfigurator.java:190)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator.createSSLEngine(SSLEngineConfigurator.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2020-08-02T09:21:48.274+0000] [glassfish 5.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1596360108274] [levelValue: 900] [[
  GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/Debug
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.<clinit>(SSLEngineImpl.java:322)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.createSSLEngineImpl(SSLContextImpl.java:610)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.engineCreateSSLEngine(SSLContextImpl.java:202)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.createSSLEngine(SSLContext.java:361)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator.createSSLEngine(SSLEngineConfigurator.java:190)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator.createSSLEngine(SSLEngineConfigurator.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2020-08-02T09:21:48.346+0000] [glassfish 5.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1596360108346] [levelValue: 900] [[
  GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.createSSLEngineImpl(SSLContextImpl.java:610)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.engineCreateSSLEngine(SSLContextImpl.java:202)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.createSSLEngine(SSLContext.java:361)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator.createSSLEngine(SSLEngineConfigurator.java:190)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator.createSSLEngine(SSLEngineConfigurator.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2020-08-02T09:21:48.351+0000] [glassfish 5.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1596360108351] [levelValue: 900] [[
  GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.createSSLEngineImpl(SSLContextImpl.java:610)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.engineCreateSSLEngine(SSLContextImpl.java:202)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.createSSLEngine(SSLContext.java:361)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator.createSSLEngine(SSLEngineConfigurator.java:190)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator.createSSLEngine(SSLEngineConfigurator.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

I am using jdk1.8.0_261 that is referred explicit in `asenv.conf`file.

**EDIT 1**:
Added server log after trying to start domain

I also tried a solution suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54357951/3477946) answer, but I think in glassfish 5.1 the grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar is already provided with version 1.9 and I still get the same error.

I am also wondering about `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/HelloExtension` because I cannot find anything about it and the described jar comes with `sun.security.ssl.HelloExtension**s**`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After searching the github issues for problems related to this I finally found a [solution that worked for me](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/22436#issuecomment-452243277):

just remove the **sun** folder in the glassfish/modules/endorsed/grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar of the server. After that glassfish 5.1 with jdk 1.8.0_261 worked in secure admin mode

Answer (score 1):

I found same error in payara server work on glass fish server.

In payara server location for "grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar" file is
"[root-payara]/glassfish/lib" remove "grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar" file from folder.

Default 'root-payara' folder in windows "c:/users/[user-name]/Payara-server"